# Error which hit the limit of JSONStore

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I found [Worklight JSONStore has no size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137432/jsonstore-worklight-size-limit) by Worklight runtime.
Does WL JSONStore API return error/error code if you add to collection and hit the size limit of your mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should get an error, but it will be a generic one like `PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE` (`-1`). I recommend testing this as part of your regular unit, funcional, etc. tests and QA process for your application. Report back if you see something unexpected.

Recently I answered a similar question *"Can the JSON offline device store be size restricted?"*. I'll add my answer here because I believe it could be helpful.

While this functionality is not baked into the core API, it should be fairly straightforward to implement.

JSONStore has an [enhance method](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_jsonstore_enhance.html) you can use to add functions to the JSONStoreInstance prototype. There's an example inside that should help.

Cordova has a [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

Note: *"size: The size of the file in bytes. (long)"*

JSONStore stores its data here:

- iOS: `[app]/Documents/wljsonstore/jsonstore.sqlite`
- Android: `/data/data/com.[app-name]/databases/wljsonstor/jsonstore.sqlite`

I talked a bit about that file in these StackOverflow answers:

- [What are the recommended ways to debug Worklight applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959984/186909)
- [JSONStore difference between 'number' and 'integer' in searchFields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15425797/186909)

Check the file size of `jsonstore.sqlite` using Cordova's File API before you add more data to your JSONStore collection.

Basically you would do something like this:

```
if(checkFileSize(collection.name+'.sqlite') < LIMIT){
  collection.add(...);
}
```

Using enhance you can wrap that logic into its own method (e.g. `collection.addWithSizeCheck(....)`) that checks the file size and calls `collection.add(...)`.

Note that the default username is `jsonstore`, hence `jsonstore.sqlite`. If you pass a username to [init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_jsonstore_init.html) it will create a new .sqlite file with that username.